# SAP PowerDesigner Data API

Tags: powerdesigner

I am want to create CDM in powerdesigner using import functionality. I have explored the option of importing excel but this requires user to refresh the imported excel in case of any changes.

What I want is to call an API, which will provide json/xml data, from powerdesigner, either desktop or web application, to generate CDM . Is this option available in powerdesigner? if yes, then how can I do it?

Comment: I'd set to answer this request with PowerDesigner Desktop, and I'd separate it in two parts: parse the JSON in whatever format you desire, and make the calls to the Automation API, to create the CDM. Whichever language you want to use is up to you, as long as it allows Automation calls. I even found several JSON parsers in vbscript (e.g. [this one](https://github.com/pravynandas/JSONToXML)), if you're into that kind of thing...

Comment: I agree, seems like the best option. I do wonder, however, at the use case. This sounds like using PowerDesigner as a diagramming tool, which it isn't.

Answer (score 0):

There is quite usable Java API which you can use basically to do anything can be done manually in PD. So you can process almost any input/ouput file to create various diagram.